# precision on inference from two distribution

Tags: statistical-inference

can someone clarify a doubt about this exercise:
the literacy rate of a nation measures the proportion of people age 15 and over who can read and write
A statistician is interested in the estimation of parameter $\theta$, the literacy rate for woman in Afghanistan and she has to choose between random samples from bernoulli or a geometric distribution (with the same $\theta$ )
i.e. given $n$ she can choose between the following exeperiments:

1. she randomly select $n$ afghani women and count the number of woman who are literate
2. she run $n$ different experiments, for each experiment, she keeps selecting woman until she finds a literate one; $Xi$ is the number of afghani woman she asks until one says she is literate

which of the 2 will give the more precise inference on $\theta$?

my attempt was to find the lowest  variance between  a bernoulli and geometric distribution to choose the more precise experiment through the inverse of fisher information
Then I do not know how to choose the more precise

Any suggestion will be appreciate